# Mysql Create Table with dynamic database name

Tags: mysql, database, dynamic

I am creating database at runtime and I want to create the tables in that database at the same time. Can anyone give me any thought on how to do that?
For Example -

I have created one database named 'mydb'
and now in the same process I am trying to create the table I am using the mysql stored procedure for the same.
My proc input will be my dbname. So, my proc looks like

```
create procedure test(IN dbname varchar(100))
begin 
    create table `dbname`.`testing`(testid int, testname varchar(45));
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [PREPARE feature](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to execute dynamic SQL.