# MySQL use variable value as database name

Tags: mysql

I have a stored procedure that should create a database using the value of the input variable but instead it just creates a database using the variable name itself.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_createdb (dbname VARCHAR(128))
BEGIN
    CREATE DATABASE dbname;
END //
```

How can I use the value of `dbname` instead of creating a database called "dbname".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql Create Table with dynamic database name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929244/mysql-create-table-with-dynamic-database-name)

Comment: Dang, why not close that one to mine below :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_createdb (dbname VARCHAR(128))
BEGIN
    SET @theSQL=CONCAT('CREATE DATABASE ',dbname);
    PREPARE stmt1 from @theSQL;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;   
END //
DELIMITER ;

call proc_createdb('fred12236');
use fred12236;
drop schema fred12236;
```

Please see the MySQL Manual page entitled [SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). Note that they invariably use a [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) and User Variables (with an @) and they are flakey if used with DECLARE (local variables).